# AMP update-cache request returns 403

Tags: java, spring, sha256, amp-html, rsa-sha256

I am trying to implement Google AMP update-cache request using [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache).

**My implementation**

As suggested in the tutorial, firstly I get the cache information from https://cdn.ampproject.org/caches.json and then I iterate through these caches to perform update.

Simplified code for single cache (as there is just one at the moment anyways):

**Main logic**

```
String firstPartUrl = "https://amp--frontend-dpo-styria--publishing-com.cdn.ampproject.org"
String secondPartUrl = "/update-cache/c/s/amp-frontend.dpo.styria-publishing.com/octopus/5267614?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1505218616"

secondPartUrl = signRequestUrl(secondPartUrl);

performRequest(firstPartUrl, secondPartUrl);
```

**Signing function**

```
private String signRequestUrl(String requestUrl) throws Exception {
    URL url = Resources.getResource("rsa/private-key-pcks8.pem");
    String privateKey = Resources.toString(url, Charsets.UTF_8);

    String signature = signSHA256RSA(requestUrl, privateKey);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(requestUrl);
    builder.append("&amp_url_signature=");
    builder.append(signature);
    return builder.toString();
}

public static String signSHA256RSA(String input, String privateKey) throws Exception {
    // Remove markers and new line characters in private key
    String realPK = privateKey.replaceAll("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replaceAll("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replaceAll("\r\n", "")//windows
            .replaceAll("\n", "");//unix

    byte[] b1 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(realPK);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(b1);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    privateSignature.initSign(kf.generatePrivate(spec));
    privateSignature.update(input.getBytes());
    byte[] s = privateSignature.sign();
    return Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(s);
}
```

My public key is published here: https://amp-frontend.dpo.styria-publishing.com/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub

URL produced by the app looks like this:
https://amp--frontend-dpo-styria--publishing-com.cdn.ampproject.org/update-cache/c/s/amp-frontend.dpo.styria-publishing.com/octopus/5267614?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1505218616&amp_url_signature=YiQ_ZEXq-FyoTQfk4YdL-n3rR0JqF6PQ8J86iCBcyNFino7t5_zSSqLR4vDoNz6o9Bj_5UbYFdpRa-J04MoL_-mizxo6M8OftcgbKjBNfgvXjG4SIzKZGxVWkBIWBLAoaEXqnkAeEsyyjBAxmX7Z3O4_GAY77Rqdb4vGKtbszSK5QHKmHAzRRYUnu2wMlYkPNTA_3yyHaZZPs0cRpksrDHLABZbGKgluMtL1lbKPSye1XK_9PBneATiSmSKlxuIyVqeFWlxwMgzEY5gz9QZCR0Tv1GvOZv6dAgqXnVR9t2vb2OYNqrR0_WO9BuNwpRu3Sz1OA1_FuukbL5G41cuj2w

**What I tried**

I even tried to follow the signing steps in the command line, but even after that the URL I obtained returned 403.

I tried following tips from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160480/using-update-cache-requests-to-update-amp-pages) (making sure that I use SHA256 and setting content-type of apikey to text/plain, but it did not help)

**My question**

Do you know why is Google AMP still returning 403? I suspected, that there might be an issue with my Base64 encoding, because the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache#rsa-keys) is not very clear about that, but I am not sure.

**EDIT**

I realized there might be a problem with the implementation of the function building `secondPartUrl` - specifically the timestamp. I created the timestamp using `ZonedDateTime.now()`, which is obviously wrong, as I am in different Timezone than UTC. However, changing it to `Instant.now()` did not help.