# openssl_pkey_get_private returning false

Tags: php, openssl

Im trying to verify some private keys but the php method **openssl_pkey_get_private()** always return **false**.
And the **openssl_error_string()** is returning:

**error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line**

```
    $return = openssl_pkey_get_private($path.'_priKEY.pem');
    if ($return === false) {
        var_dump(openssl_error_string());
    }
```

Tried this with private key extracted from .pfx file, other from .p12 file, and even an self generated key (with openssl). 
Already tried with "RSA PRIVATE KEY", "ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY" and "PRIVATE KEY". Nothing changes.

**Private key content:**

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0B
[......................]
Wxdadnf7MB7DicckIZTKVy1L
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Is this .pem file protected by a passphrase?

Comment: No, im not using passphrase.

Comment: It works for me, for both PKCS#1 and PKCS#8-formatted RSA keys. What is the exact content of you `$path` variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you did not provide the right format for the path to the file. Make sure it starts with `file://`, followed by and absolute or relative path. Yes, if you choose an absolute path, then the path to the filename will be something like `file:///absolute/path/to/keyfile.pem`, starting with three slashes. For relative paths, it will be `file://relative/path/to/keyfile.pem`.

According to the [documentation for openssl_pkey_get_private()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php), you can provide the key either as a path to a file, or as a string containing the actual key. Only if the value starts with `file://`, it is interpreted as the path (URI) to a file. Otherwise, the value is interpreted as a string containing the PEM-encoded key. In the latter case, it expects a start line that it recognizes as PEM, like `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`. That is why you get that error message, your argument neither starts with `file://` nor with a PEM start line.

If you do not like the `file://` path format, you could always read the contents of the file yourself before providing it to `openssl_pkey_get_private()`, something like:

```
$return = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents($path.'_priKEY.pem'));
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect! The problem is with the path, i was using the absolute path but without the "file:://" on the beginning. Also, passing the content worked too.

Comment: @BigBoss My pleasure and good luck with your OpenSSL endeavors.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek hello, I have the exact PEMK format
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
AO5WYGngGjnaLCbJyFpFGShODX8VUtv64w1KcIAEPrMVKgbrj1UO9D3dPi4VdyT5
5jG9ETWPydZ9UyXMdsVvB0w=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
Still I get false.  My code is $PrivateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($Pem);
$Pem contains the above string. Can you please help.

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to next URL.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php

To narrow down your issue, please use *same directory for your php file and key file* and try this working code.

**Working code**

```
$keyfile="file://".__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."key.pem"; //absolute path
$key = openssl_pkey_get_private($keyfile);

if ($key === false) {
    var_dump(openssl_error_string());
}else{
    var_dump($key);
}
```

Also please refer to 
[Openssl and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774127/openssl-and-php/57814220#57814220)