# ERROR - Unable to load signing key. Can't sign my text with my Private Key - PHP

Tags: php, openssl, private-key, php-openssl

I can't instanciate my `$pemkey` whit a relative path in my php code. When I try to instanciate my key with `openssl_pkey_get_private` the program doesn't find it.

Here is my code :

```
$pemkey = openssl_pkey_get_private("file:///licensePrivateKey.pem");
if (! $pemkey ){
    echo "ERROR - Unable to load signing key.";
    die();
}
```

And here are my files :

- folder

  - download_file.php
  - licensePrivateKey.pem

(Sorry can't display images lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error by creating an absolute path with `dirname(__FILE__)` and and my file name. Here's the code :

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
$key = "licensePrivateKey.pem";
$pemkey = openssl_pkey_get_private("file://".$path."/".$key);
if (! $pemkey ){
    echo "ERROR - Unable to load signing key.";
    var_dump(openssl_error_string());
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this note on PHP manual website https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php#114998
*So you only have to concatenate "file://" with an existing path string in every case*

This looks like an absolute path **/licensePrivateKey.pem**
You are using windows or unix system?

Comment: I'm using a Windows system. and the path is supposed to be realtive, so did I do smth wrong ?

Comment: Putting 2 slashes only also shows the error message

Comment: check for errors var_dump(openssl_error_string()); for more info visit [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593674/openssl-pkey-get-private-returning-false)